# Ubuntu 20.04 reverted to 18.04 on it's own

Tags: server, versions

This has me really confused.  I have been running Ubuntu Server 20.04 for months.  I was logged in from my Windows machine through SSH (I normally leave this open all the time).  I have several drives on my sever mapped to windows.  When I got home from work tonight I saw a message that said failure to reconnect to ### - already connected.  There was also a time out error from Putty stating that I was disconnected from the server.  I restarted Putty and logged back in with no problem but found that my Ubuntu version is now 18.04 LTS.  I checked and the last reboot was on 12-6-21 - 10 days ago.  And I have not intentionally reverted back to 18.04.  How did this happen.  I am running VEEAM on the server with daily cron backups but don't see how VEEAM could have did a restore on it's own.  Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: mayb read thru the syslog to see if you can get any ideas? `cat /var/log/syslog | less`

Comment: Ubuntu has no tools/capacity to revert to prior versions (upgrade tools go to newer, data restores from backups take users back but that's a user implemented feature). The version though is just a text file, so can be easily changed.  From your description I wonder what you're really running as going backwards requires a user to setup that data.restore.feature and implies you never fully upgraded to me in the first place & need to check/verify details.

Comment: What version name shows when you run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? Does it show bionic or focal?

Comment: You should check your veeam logs to make sure it didn't do some kind of odd recovery issue or someone with veeam access reverted your system.  There are *zero* mechanisms to revert an upgrade unless a full restore via a back up system like via Veeam happened.

Comment: syslog doesn't really show anything that indicates a problem.  sources.list is showing bionic and not focal.  guiverc, I was sure I upgraded because I had to deal with all the snap stuff and networking issues present with 20.04.  I guess I can mount a Veeam backup from a few days back and check my sources.list file in the backup.

Comment: Thomas Ward - Veeam logs show nothing about a restore.  Veeam interface shows a successful backup at 6am.